# What is it called when you add 'im' to 'possible'?

Tags: prefixes

I took the ESL certification test and I was wondering: what is it called when you add 'im' to 'possible'?

Comment: Thrice didn't cut it for me :( I'm still lost.

Comment: Four times was not enough for me either. What does _was what is it called when you add 'im' to 'possible'_ mean? I read it as _How is the process of forming words like 'impossible' called?_

Comment: It's called *defeatism*! :)

Comment: @Robusto: I LOL'ed.

Answer (score 20):

It's funny because you tagged this question `prefixes` — well, adding *im-* to *possible* is called [prefixation](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/prefixation).

(Making a word have the opposite meaning by adding a negating prefix is also a form of [negation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negation_%28linguistics%29).)

Comment: I didn't even notice the tag. Good one.

Comment: Found morphophonemic alternation - which I guess has to do with the im rather than in :)

Comment: @RegDwight:  My initial assumption was that the OP was asking for *negation*.

Answer (score 8):

Adding a prefix to a word is called *prefixation*, as Kosmonaut pointed out.

A further point: [as](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?term=impossible) [several](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/impossible) [dictionaries](http://education.yahoo.com/reference/dictionary/entry/impossible) [say](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/impossible), *impossible* comes from the prefix *in-* and *possible*, so why is ***in + possible = impossible***, rather than **inpossible*?

The answer is that *in-* becomes *im-* before words starting with 'p', 'b', or 'm' (as in *impatient*, *imbalance*, *immature*, etc.), because of a process of euphonic sound change known in Sanskrit as [**sandhi**](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sandhi) (pron. "sun-thee"), a term that appears to have some currency among general linguists as well. Specifically, it's a form of internal sandhi (the kind that would be called *parasavarṇa sandhi* in Sanskrit, but I don't know the equivalent term in English linguistics).

Comment: @Jasper: Is assimilation the term for sandhi in general, or for consonant sandhi, or for the specific type of sandhi where -n becomes -m before p/b/m? (And becomes the velar nasal before velar consonants, etc., which are not reflected in spelling.)

Comment: Outside Sanskrit studies, the word "sandhi" tends to be used mainly for processes at the juncture of separate words; but this might be called "internal sandhi". "Assimilation" is the kind of change - one sound taking on the characteristics of a neighbouring sound - and most often applies where separate morphemes come together,  but can apply in other circumstances. For example "bank" is pronounced  with the 'ng' sound of "bang" because of the following velra.

Comment: @Colin: Thanks, I guess what we have here (and in your examples, and what I was looking for) is assimilation, specifically nasal assimilation.

Answer (score 4):

To add a prefix to a word is called *prefixation*, as Kosmonaut points out.

To add any kind of affix (prefix, suffix, infix, circumfix) to a word is called *affixation*.

To form a new word out of another word by means of affixation is called *derivation* or sometimes *agglutination*.

Answer (score 4):

The *semantic* process (effect on the meaning) is called "negation" or "privation".