# What's the opposite of "concatenate" in programming?

Tags: single-word-requests, antonyms

To concatenate means *to string together different things.* Concatenating "snow" and "ball" produces "snowball." But what would the opposite action be? What is the name of the action used to derive two words from one?

(My dictionaries don't list any antonyms, and Googling revealed *how* to do the opposite but not what it's called.)

*Edit: I had programming parlance in mind, so I've reflected that in the question title.*

Comment: Seven people so far think this question is worth answering, but only one person thinks to downvote it. Interesting. Any feedback I should hear?

Comment: Do you have any feedback that would help for the future?

Comment: That's unfortunate. I didn't find any antonyms listed in dictionaries, and Googling didn't reveal much. I don't see consensus here, so I'm inclined to believe the answer isn't so simple. Regardless, I appreciate the feedback … helps me understand.

Comment: I've rescinded my downvote, as I feel that it is harder than I thought to actually research this.

Comment: I downvoted because you didn't *show* you had done research. Based on your comment, I'm rescinding mine as well.

Comment: Ohhhhhhhh. I get it now. It's like when the professor wants you to "show your work." I will revise. Thank you!

Comment: @tajmo--Yup! Hopefully this will help you with future questions. Research gets more positive responses, especially when we know you did it

Comment: This may be why some languages (e.g. PHP) opt for implode/explode for these functions.

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Looking strictly at the Latin roots of *concatenate*:

> *concatenare*, from Latin *com*- + *catenare*, to chain [MW]

**com-** is the [Latin prefix](http://www.usu.edu/markdamen/Wordpower/handouts/lataffix.pdf) meaning "*together, with*."

**dis-** is the Latin prefix meaning "*apart*."

(**de-** means "*down* or *away from*," so you can make the case for that as well.)

So: **discatenate**, or **decatenate**.

Edit: As I (and FF) noted in a comment, *decatenate* is used in [biology/biochemistry](http://www.biology-online.org/dictionary/Decatenation) to describe the unlinking of a chain of chemical elements.

Comment: Realize the page you link to uses con/com to mean the same thing, but in this case don't you mean con, and not com, or is there some meaning beyond the document you linked to. Also, in my opinion comparing an organic seperation to the synthetic nature on written language is problematic. Meaning one is aproximate, the other exact - I personally am unable to believe I'd ever you that word in the context provided, though easily am able to imagine using it within the context of bio sciences.

Comment: A precision: "com" does not mean "together, with" in Latin. It derives from "cum" which means "with" (not "together") in Latin.

Comment: Not to be confused with "decapitate"  ^^

Comment: @LordScree It's only confusing if you _capitate_ (_concapitate_?) often.

Comment: @VincentRobert According to [this site](http://www.class.uidaho.edu/luschnig/EWO/24.htm): "com- with, together {com- before b, p, m; cor- before r; col- before l; co- before h, gn and usually before vowels; con- before all other consonants.}"

Comment: @blunders See preceding comment to Vincent Robert

Comment: @blunders: The prefix *com-*, when used before any stem not beginning with *p* or *b*, becomes *con-*. (More precisely, it becomes the nasal consonant corresponding to the vowel following it — a process called nasal assimilation, see [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/10725/77) and [here](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/28709/are-there-any-nk-or-nc-words-in-english-where-there-isnt-a-ng-before) — so it appears as 'm' only before *p*, *b* or *m.)*

Comment: @Gnawme I was only pointing that the Latin word for "with" is "cum" and that "com-" is a derivative of this Latin word.

Comment: @Gnawme decapitation is usually only one-way.  On a similar, but completely unrelated tangent, if you "decapitulate", is that the same as surrendering, then (whilst your enemy is patting you down to look for hidden weapons) kneeing him or her in the private parts? (I'll stop now...)

Answer (score 89):

I would use *split* to mean the opposite of *concatenate*. I don't know if there's a better choice, but I've seen *split* used with this particular meaning in mind. Of course you should also specify *how* you will split the word, since you could split it at any point(s), and into more than 2 parts.

Comment: *Split* is the word you usually see in code where a programmer has to do this. There is *uncatenate*, used particularly by those DNA boffins who habitually [catenate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concatenate) rather than *concatenate* things together. I don't recommend that for general use, but it's so obvious people do sometimes use it in other contexts.

Comment: Etymologically speaking, uncatenate makes more sense than catenate. At least it means to un-"chain".

Comment: Actually, chem boffins use [decatenate](http://genesdev.cshlp.org/content/11/19/2580.long) as the opposite of catenate.

Comment: @FumbleFingers That was my first thought.  Splitting seemed like the obvious opposite of concatenation, but that is only because they are commonly used when programming.

Comment: Perl uses *split()* and *join()*.
Python uses *split()* and *join()*.

Comment: `join` and `concatenate` aren't *exactly* analogous in the programming world. To `join` is to `concatenate` the elements in a list, but each separated by some delimiter.

Comment: @lwburk: Good point but (1) the delimiter is often the emty string, and (2) whatever "opposite" of concatenate the OP is looking for, it seems fair to say it will result in a list of words... so I'd say the OP *is* looking for the opposite of `join` rather than of `concatenate` (which is meaningless: monoids don't necessarily have inverses), and thus `split` is exactly the right word.

Comment: Ummm....  `"".join(<list>)`  Voila.

Comment: split() has no way to discern where to split "snowball". split() implies that you have a character to split on. The case that the OP is asking about is more generally referred to as tokenization. See my answer below.

Comment: @FumbleFingers +1 for *uncatenate* and *boffins*

Comment: @lwburk more importantly, `.split` needs a delimiter. concatenation does not.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: **split needs delimiter. concatenation does not.** so split is not (exactly) the 'opposite', it's just (closely) related. Albeit the whole thing depends on what you mean by 'opposite'.

Answer (score 15):

> the action used to derive two words from one

**decompose** - *to separate or resolve into constituent parts or elements; disintegrate*

(in the same vein as "deconstruct", which has already been mentioned)

> "Snowball" can be decomposed into its constituent parts: "snow" and "ball".

Comment: Closely related would be **dissect.**

Answer (score 13):

When getting the original words from a word formed by concatenating words, or possibly modified parts of words, the previously-mentioned *divide* and *split* spring naturally to mind.  However, the verb *[cleave](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/cleave)* has to recommend it its sense "to split along a natural plane of division" (of a crystal), which can be seen as metaphor for dividing the composite word into natural parts.  Another verb that suggests splitting at natural divisions is *[burst](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/burst)*, in its sense "to separate formfeed at perforation lines".

Comment: *Cleave* is worth a point from me.

Comment: I think *cleave* should be avoided in a context where OP is asking for an antonym, given that [it's already its own antonym](http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/29805)

Comment: @FumbleFingers - Makes it all the handier -- use it for both sticking the words together, and taking them apart again :)

Comment: Good application of Occam's Razor there - *"Do not multiply entities (or words) unnecessarily"!* :)

Comment: @FumbleFingers Cleave is almost never used in popular use to mean anything but split. That said I think split is still the better word, and being completely unambiguous is a plus.

Comment: @Ben Brocka: Each to their own usage. I'm happy to use/read it with either meaning, because there's always context. I applauded jwpat7's comment because it tickled my fancy, but I wouldn't suggest it for technical usage - fairly obviously we'd just end up with a standard library function called *uncleave([SomeSoonToBeExPartner])*.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Cleavage is also a technical term used to describe the splitting of things, the most formal use of the word I've heard.

Comment: I'm not so old I can't appreciate a good cleavage! But our good ole Queen is about as formal as it gets here in the UK, and I don't recall anyone ever mentioning hers. Methinks it would be lesse-majeste, rather than formality! :)

Answer (score 10):

I'm going to go with **separate**.  I think it's one of the closest available to the desired meaning, and it has the bonus of rhyming with (and being at least vaguely close in length and syllables as) *concatenate*.

I don't think there's a truly great answer, mainly because *concatenate* isn't the best antonym for anything else.  Many people mentioned *split*, which is a perfectly good word for the job, but the best antonym for *split* would probably be *join*.

The approach of using *dis-*, *de-*, or *un-* is certainly logical enough, but such a word feels constructed and unnatural without the benefit of widespread use.  (Even if such words are in actual use, they are still far less frequently used than *concatenate*, especially in nontechnical contexts).

Comment: not to mention split and join both imply a delimiter; concatenation have no delimiter. yours is the right approach.

Comment: on an off note, feeling constructed also applies to 'concatenate', if you ask me. I lack an alternative. Perhaps 'linking', [as robrambusch put it](http://english.stackexchange.com/a/53817/23199) (I can see where this have failed to gain ground.) Regardless, at least I always felt it sounding arbitrary and/or unnatural. I'm non-native if that puts me into a position for anything.

Answer (score 9):

I think of concatenate as a *programming* word so I'll give you a *programming* antonym:

**parse** - 'to resolve (as a sentence) into component parts of speech and describe them grammatically'

As concatenate means to "link together" parse means to separate out.

Comment: That has a more natural feel as an antonym; concatenate is so formal while split so informal … parse sounds like the perfect nemesis.

Comment: *parse* seems a little too specific for me to be a good antonym.

Comment: `Parse` infers intelligence behind the action.  `Concatenate` doesn't require any intelligence, just brute force, put this thing after that thing.  `Split` has the same feeling for me where brute force rather than intelligence comes into mind (other than when slitting atoms lol). Same with `separate` for the antonym, doesn't require intelligence.

Comment: It's not a good antonym, and I don't think it has to do with how specific or general *parse* is. *Parse* just isn't the counterpart to concatenate. Parsing involves gleaning the structure and/or meaning of something, ultimately so we can understand it. Concatenation, especially in programming, is just mindlessly joining things together.

Comment: I guess the real action of reversing a concatenation would involve parsing, since the splits need to fall in places that make sense. That is, you can mindlessly concatenate, but it requires intelligence to pull things back apart. That doesn't make it an antonym, but that does make it the opposite.

Comment: Question edited to clarify.

Comment: Ab but, parse sounds like it's a necessary step to properly "splitting," judging from its use in computing as a type of analysis.  Ironically, analyze literally means to cut apart, but it is more likened to the measuring that happens before any cutting.

Comment: If you concatenate the words "link" and "together" you get "linktogether". If you *split* "linktogether" you might get "linkto" and "gether". If you *parse* "linktogether" you get "link" and "together". Ladies and gentlemen of the jury - I rest my case.

Comment: @tajmo: actually, I would say that splitting is a sub-step of parsing. At least the way I code. ;)

Comment: My experience has been that the word parse is the same as transform, and that splitting a string is one of many different actions, including simple reading a string and writing it. Beyond that, believe the poster's reference to finding an anyonymn to understand the meaning was just a way they attempted to find a meaningful word. The word they're looking for is stemming based on the example given in my opinion.

Comment: Sometimes when I parse something, the result is not the constituent parts of what I started with... So if I parse a concatenated string in programming, I may end up with only a substring.

Comment: There's a lot of logic about parsing being smart and concatenation being dumb, but that's unavoidable. There's only one was to concatenate a string can be split lots of ways. It's the English/programming equivalent of the second law of thermodynamics.

Comment: In programming, we `parse` some text into data structures conveying the *logical* structure of the original text (which we have to assume has some particular kind of structure). The opposite of parsing is to render the data structures into text; not concatenation. I wouldn't feel comfortable saying "parse" is the opposite of "concatenate", because I wouldn't expect anyone at all to understand me if I said "the opposite of parsing" and meant concatenation.

Answer (score 5):

There are lots of words you could use: *[dichotomize,](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/dichotomize) [separate,](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/separate)* and *[divide,](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/divide)* to name a few. As mentioned by others, *split* also works.

*Dichotomize* is not very common, so you may want to avoid using it, for fear of sounding pretentious. *Divide* is nice because it can be used even if you are splitting the word into more than two parts.

*Extract* is another viable possibility.

Comment: I like `separate` from your list. I think it can go head-to-head against `split` any day  :)

Comment: @DMCS: The word separate and split have different meanings in my opinion. For example, try replacing the word separate with split in the following sentence: "Spaces separate words in a sentence." Possible, I'm over thinking it, but don't believe they've got the same meaning.

Comment: Now my rep isn't a perfect multiple of five >:( Silly downvoter ruined my fun.

Comment: I concatenate things all the time.. and  apart from the academic or the semantic.. its practical opposite is ***divide***.  Think not about multiplication, but what concatenation actually implies - and then take it apart. :-)

Answer (score 4):

In general, I'm inclined to agree that **split** is a suitable term for retrieving the component words within, say, *"snowball"*. It's certainly a standard term in a programming context, for the kind of trivial separation dumb code easily performs.

But with a slightly less "transparent" word, such as [goshawk](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/goshawk), I think it might be better to say you [deconstruct](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/deconstruct) it into *"goose"* and *"hawk"*.

> deconstruct - *to expose or dismantle [a] structure*.

Comment: The concatenation of "goose" and "hawk" would be "goosehawk" (or possibly "hawkgoose", not "goshawk".

Comment: I started by endorsing *split* for the "lossless, reversible" computer-oriented process. The context I'm proposing for *deconstruct* is language-based - *goshawk* is a compound word created from two identifiable components, even if you don't want to accept that those components were *concatenated*, since one of them has transformed since then.

Comment: *Deconstruct*, *Dismantle*, *Disassemble* are good for compound words where a transformation has occurred but in the OP's example of *snowball* (the concatenation of *snow* and *ball*), there is no transformation. If it had been *snoball*, then *deconstruct* would make more sense then *split*.

Comment: @FrustratedWithFormsDesigner: I think one issue with ELU is that software-oriented users are massively over-represented. I certainly don't begrudge you the points, but I'm sure the fact that this question attracts interests from programmers is what lies behind the high number of votes for *"split"*. I'd never have expected it to be otherwise, but I primarily posted my offering in an attempt to redress the balance a bit (the upvotes currently stand at 36:2, so I guess that was a somewhat forlorn hope! :)

Answer (score 3):

I agree with most of what has been said about split/join. However, it's interesting to note that split has no way to know what the root words in your example are. That is, that the split should occur between snow and ball.

The more general case is referred to as tokenization. Split typically implies a character such as space, comma, CRLF, etc. to split on.

So, for example, a tokenizer would have enough information about the compositional root words of English to recognize that snow and ball are the tokens and break down the compound words accordingly.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokenize

Answer (score 2):

It's interesting Frustrated would suggest 'split' because in the programming language Perl, the functions to respectively join two strings, and split two strings in half are respectively: Concatenate, and Split!

I'm pretty sure the guy who wrote Perl had the same dilemma, and that's the best he could come up with!

I guess you could make up a word, and say uncatenate, decatenate or something along those lines.

Comment: I've used those functions in Perl. :)

Comment: You posted as I commented to @Frustrated's answer. I don't know even Perl, so that's certainly not my reason for backing "split". I'm not sure anybody ever says *"decatenate"* - but as I noted, *"uncatenate"* is already out there and thriving.

Comment: Actually, the functions in perl are called *split* and *join*   The . operator is called the concatenation operator, but the appropriate function is *join*

Answer (score 2):

As a software developer I prefer **split**, **unlink** and **disjoin** but typically pick any that best describes the context and usage of what I'm creating. Not sure if that helps any.

Answer (score 2):

Splitting the text would describe the action, and to do so would require a separator, or rules of separations. Stemming would define the linguistic concept.

Answer (score 2):

I'd use *stem* if your original meaning of concatenate tended towards *compound.*

Answer (score 1):

If you were of a software bent, I would say **substring**.  While I don't think it is legitimately a verb, I have heard it often used as one when describing the act of breaking down a string of characters into any number of smaller strings, whether they be individual characters, or several.

Keep in mind that substring-ing does not assume that the resulting strings will be intelligible.

Comment: Agree, the poster is asking about linguistic splitting of words, which is called stemming. A substring as you point out is a string which orginates from other string, for example if I delete all the numbers in this string "r2e2a2d" I get the substring "read"; meaning that to get a substring splitting a string is not require. I would also agree I've heard substring used as a verb, which is an incorrect use of the word in my opinion.

Comment: On the whole, I am pretty lax about my use of the English language ( I figure if the English language is going to be lax with its rules, I will be too) and I tend to verb a lot of words (such as the word verb) which probably should not be.

Answer (score 1):

In programming specifically, there isn't an opposite of "concatenate". The concept makes no sense.

"Split" is probably the least silly alternative. But I wouldn't call it the opposite of concatenation *in a programming context*. In general usage, perhaps.

Nearly every programming language has an operator for string concatenation: `++` in Haskell, `+` in Python, `.` in PHP, etc. No language has an operator for the opposite of concatenation.

If you tell me "I concatenate 'shadows' and 'linger'", then I know exactly what the result is. If you tell me "I split 'shadowslinger'", then I have no idea what the result is; the operation is not well defined. I might guess that it would be "shadows" and "linger". But it could easily be "shadow" and "slinger". Or it might only be coincidence that it looks like English, and the split could have nothing to do with that.

Comment: +1 because it doesn't make sense most of the time.  However, you did remind me of one language that does have something like that operation:  bash has [remove patterns](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/bash-shell-parameter-substitution-2.html) (Section 4 & 4.1)

Answer (score 1):

The opposite word to *concatenate* is *dissociate*. *Concatenation* means joining two words and *dis-concatenate* or *dissociate* (*dis-associate*) is the synonymy.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a list from [Thesaurus.com](http://thesaurus.com/browse/concatenate), down at the bottom of the page:

> Main Entry:   consolidate
>
> Part of Speech:   verb
>
> Definition:   combine; make firm
>
> Synonyms:     add to, amalgamate, amass, band, bind, blend, build up, bunch up, cement, centralize, compact, compound, **concatenate** , concentrate, condense, conjoin, connect, densen, develop, federate, fortify, fuse, harden, hitch, hitch on, hook up with, incorporate, join, league, mass, meld, mix, plug into, pool, reinforce, render solid, secure, set, slap on, solidify, stabilize, strengthen, tack on, tag on, team up with, thicken, throw in together, tie in, tie up with, unify
>
> Antonyms:     disjoin, disperse, divide, part, separate

Given the difference in meaning between "consolidate" and "concatenate", I'd limit the antonyms in that list to "divide", "part", and "separate".

Answer (score 0):

In most programming languages with C-based syntax, concatenate usually means to link strings or characters together.  The fact that the strings usually happen to be words is somewhat irrelevant, because the computer (and hence the programmer) is handling them as a sequence of characters; like linking track from a toy train set together.  The answer depends on what you're trying to do.  One possibility is 'parse' as others suggest, because it means to separate out an aggregated entity, like a string of characters.  However, parsing also implies computationally manipulating each piece or segment as it's separated from the whole.  Another is 'split,' because that also applies to strings.

If the originator of the question is translating or editing a programming text, it would be best to verify your choice with the programming language of concern.  Every programming language has its own parlance, largely influenced by the standard functions available in each language's respective code libraries or API's (application programming interface).  For an example of what I'm talking about, here's java's api:  http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/lang/String.html

A word of caution: programming jargon is dictated largely by the programming language being used, and by extension, it's syntax.  Webster's thesaurus or the classical roots of a word probably aren't your best resources for answering this question.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on what you mean by it, antonyms of *catenate* or the needlessly wordier *concatenate* might be *detach* or perhaps *separate* — but I’m rather unfond of *unjoin*. ☹

However, if you actually mean to chomp letters off the end and discard them, you probably want the mysteriously underused ***apocopate***, which abbreviates or shortens a word, usually by a letter or a syllable. It comes to English right out of Latin, and in turn right out of Greek  *ἀποκοπή*.

Answer (score 0):

*Truncate* — Shorten (something) by cutting off the top or the end: "a truncated cone shape".