# Is "catenate" used in IT parlance?

Tags: word-choice, verbs, prefixes, programming, computing

When I was doing my IT degree in the 80s we learned that, in programming terms, concatenation was the act of joining two strings together.

Recently I was reading a technical manual and came across the word *catenate* in the same context.

A quick look at [dictionary.com](http://dictionary.reference.com) seems to indicate that catenate is used in a biological context. [Another post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53812/whats-the-opposite-of-concatenate-in-programming) on this site discusses *concatenate* and *decatenate* — the use of *con-* and *de-* as prefixes on *catenate* to indicate the construction or destruction of string sequences.

I'm curious as to whether IT professionals are now using the simpler word *catenate* when talking about concatenation?

Comment: I did my IT degree in late 80's but I still know what's what, only sometimes doing IT things now being a BA. Where have you been Bill? Have you gone to the other side? Shock and horror. Seriously it's always been and always will be concatenate. Incidentally, when I need to see all the non-printables in a file then I "send the cat to the vet" i.e. cat -vet the_file.

Comment: I think this is General Reference. Google ["software concatenate"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22software+concatenate%22&oq=%22software+concatenate%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8): 81,600 hits. But ["software catenate"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22software+catenate%22&oq=%22software+catenate%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) gets only 49 hits, many of which clearly aren't even English.

Comment: @FumbleFingers You just need to [Google harder](http://www.google.com/search?num=50&hl=en&safe=off&client=opera&hs=t3T&tbo=d&rls=en&channel=suggest&q=perl+catenate&nirf=perl+concatenate&sa=X&ei=qjikUOvROcLFyAH5vYBA&ved=0CDIQ8BYoAQ&biw=1088&bih=721).

Comment: @tchrist: I already Googled "tighter" - you'll note that my search terms are in quotes - doing that with ["perl catenate"](http://www.google.co.uk/search?q=%22perl+catenate%22&oq=%22perl+catenate%22&sugexp=chrome,mod=18&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8) returns just 2 hits. Your favourite language is well below the radar!

Comment: @FumbleFingers That is because you are doing the query wrong.  There are many instances of *catenate* used in conjunction with *perl*.  It just is not a literal bigram, is all.  So what?

Comment: @tchrist: Why do you insist on saying what I do is "wrong"? I *chose* to use those quotes, for reasons which (still) make sense to me. Even if you can't figure them out for yourself, that hardly justifies denigrating my methodology just because it doesn't give the answer *you* want.

Comment: The **perl** reference resonated, as the author of this particular book could very well be a perl developer.

Comment: Catnip might be a better alternative -:)

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/53812/whats-the-opposite-of-concatenate-in-programming

Comment: @Bill: Is the author called Tom Christiansen? :)

Answer (score 8):

No, IT professionals are (mostly) still using the word *concatenate*. I've never heard anyone use *catenate*.

There's a command called `cat`, but it's short for the longer word rather than *catenate*. According to its own help:

> Concatenate FILE(s), or standard input, to standard output.

On Stack Overflow there's [4,150 results for *concatenate*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=concatenate&submit=search) (98.3%) but only [70 for *catenate*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=catenate&submit=search) (1.7%), and [5,000+ results for *concatenated*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=concatenated&submit=search) (~99.8%) but only [11 for *catenated*](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=catenated&submit=search) (~0.2%).

Likewise, searching code on GitHub gives [619,288 results for *concatenate*](https://github.com/search?q=concatenate&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=) (97.8%) and [14,225 for *catenate*](https://github.com/search?q=catenate&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=) (2.2%).

Finally, despite the suggestion elsewhere that *discatenate* would be the opposite of *concatenate*, *discatenate* is not in common IT use: [1 result on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=decatenate&submit=search) and [0 code results at GitHub](https://github.com/search?q=decatenate&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=). This is a problem with single word requests: someone has asked what the opposite would be, and in the accepted answer someone has come up with a new word by looking at the roots. The answer with the most votes is the much clearer *split*, which has [3,110 Stack Overflow results](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=split) and [8,001,847 on GitHub's code search](https://github.com/search?q=split&repo=&langOverride=&start_value=1&type=Code&language=).

Comment: I’ve used *catenate*, but it gets me funny looks.