# Concatenate vs. Catenate

Tags: meaning, differences

What is the difference between ***concatenate*** and ***catenate***?

Are the words interchangeable?

> *[concatenate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/concatenate)*: 1. To connect or link in a series or chain.  2. *Computer Science* To arrange (strings of characters) into a chained list.
>   *[catenate](http://www.thefreedictionary.com/catenate)*: To connect in a series of ties or links; form into a chain.

Background: Which is more natural in the case of a C function like `strcat(dest, src)`:

```
char* ConcatenateString(char* dest, char* src);
```

or

```
char* CatenateString(char* dest, char* src);
```

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about [naming (including naming variables and functions in programming)](http://english.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic).

Comment: As Janus says, since this is a function name, as far as the English language is concerned you can name it Susan. I will add I think this is general reference to boot.

Comment: Although related, I would never use catenate in programming. The word used everywhere is concatenate

Comment: Although unrelated, I would never write my own `strcat` function when the C library provides a perfectly good one :-)

Comment: Reopening, based on the edits made.  Original post was clearly off-topic due to the "no function naming" rule.  But, with that gone, I agree with the other re-open voters: "general reference" is a stretch here - even after consulting two dictionaries, the difference between the two words is far from obvious to me.

Comment: After consulting two dictionaries, the lack of difference between the two words is obvious to me.  They are the same word; one literally means "to chain together" and the other means "to chain" (without the "together" prefix, but in the exact same sense).

Comment: Related: http://english.stackexchange.com/questions/91244/is-catenate-used-in-it-parlance

Comment: in the APL programming language, the operation is called "catenate."

Comment: Note that the signature of a C function like `strcat` is inherently semantically ambiguous in exactly the relevant way: `strcat(string1, string2)` means "I want to mutate `string1` to catenate it with `string2`", while `strcat(buffer, string1); strcat(buffer, string2)` means "I want to create a new string in `buffer` that is the contents of `string1` and `string2` catenated".

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I'm a programmer and **concatenate** would definitely be the standard and most natural-sounding term. But judging by the definitions of the terms, this seems to just be a matter of convention.

You could argue that all chains chain something together and thus concatenate is etymologically redundant, but concatenate has won out in modern English. Note that there are a few million Google hits for **concatenate** and less than a tenth of that for **catenate**.

Comment: Side note: Okasaki, in his famous [Purely functional data structures](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) book, consistently uses "catenate", but it's indeed one of the rare examples I have ever come by.

Comment: I came here because I was reading Purely Functional Data Structures and was trying to find out the difference between concatenate and catenate. Small world, at least where catenate is concerned.

Comment: Ironically, the Unix command-line program to [con]catenate files is called "cat", rather than "con" or "concat". The man page for the Plan 9 implementation uses the term "catenate": http://man.cat-v.org/plan_9/1/cat, although Plan 9 appears to stand alone here.

Comment: The two terms are not interchangeable actually. *con*catenate means to catenate to self. This is why you don't see *con*catenate often in functional programming, it implies a side-effect

Comment: @LorinHochstein And even then, the Plan 9 man page gives up on "catenate" soon after: "`cat file1 file2 >file3` *concatenates* the first two files and places the result on the third." Also, Okasaki brought me here, too.

Comment: @Clément Notation as a tool of thoughts by Kenneth Iverson also uses "catenate" instead of "concatenate"

Comment: Dunno about you folks but from now on I'm saving a syllable and replacing that annoying word with "catenate"

Answer (score 4):

*Based on @LorinHochstein's comment to @LukeBradford's answer*

Let's break down **concatenate**

- `con` means "with" but with what?
- `catenate`. Oh okay so we are adding something to `self` (or `this` for the OOP programmers out there)

**Catenate**

We are adding pieces together, any pieces will do.

**Con-Catenate**

We are adding pieces together and since our current text (`this`) is the originator of the request it must become our root text so that other pieces will be added to `this`